# MVC replacement for web form user controls (ASCX)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm quiet newbie to ASP.NET MVC world.  In Web Form we can write a user control and encapsulate all the details within. We can then reuse the control on N number of pages which is a good code-reuse.

I would like to do the same in MVC 3/4 and haven't had any lucks. Could someone please help me with how above can be achieved?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no exact equivilent.  There are, however, ways to reuse code.  You can create HtmlHelper extensions (like the Html.Whatever() methods), Or you can use Partial Views, or you can use templates.  All of these do different things, but they offer various ways to reuse code.

Comment: Thanks @Mystere Man, any idea which option is best to use?

Comment: @flybyte - there is no such thing as "best to use", each does things differently, you use whichever one works best for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the closest thing to an ASCX in MVC is a [RenderAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703541.aspx). 
Similarly to a user control, you can have your partial view binded to a specific action that is independent from the container view and it's action.